# Cross Domain Active Directory Authentication

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

We have a website running on a different AD domian then we need to authenticate with. For reasons I will not go into, we can not allow a trust between them.

So we have:

Rackspace.Domain 
SuperDuperEnterpriseDomain

The website is running at rackspace under their domain and we need to be sure they are authenticated on

Is there a way to in C# to check to see if a user exists on another domain? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are getting a SuperDuperEnterpriseDomain's username and password, use [`DsBindWithCred`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675961(v=vs.85).aspx).  Note that this function fails with Access Denied even when the credentials are technically valid, such as the account being locked out.  Since you are not joined to the target domain, you won't be able to call LogonUser to get finer details on why the credentials are invalid.

For code, see my [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12676430/628981).  You can replace the SecureString's with regular strings if you don't mind the security implications.