# Generating derived key from a password stored in a SecureString

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

The [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) class derives a new cryptographic key from a given string password. As I understand it, this is supposed to increase the security of the given keys as you never have to store the key permanently - it can always be derived from a value known to the user. However, since it only takes a `string` value as input the original password stays around in memory until it's GC'd. It seems to me that this is a potential security issue just as dangerous as storing the key itself on the system. The .NET framework provides a [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) implementation to protect the password in memory. But Rfc2898DeriveBytes does not accept a secure string.

Is there any way to generate a crypto key from a SecureString?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734043/rfc2898derivebytes-pbkdf2-securestring-is-it-possible-to-use-a-secure-string

Comment: Or, to answer the question: if there is no platform API that does the derivation, it is useless to create `SecureString` instances.

Comment: Yep - it's an exact dupe. Wonder why it didn't come up when I searched for it on SO. Rfc2898DeriveBytes is a rare enough class I would expect it to have found that :(

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with just using `SecureString.ToString()` when initializing the crypto class? When the method ends, the return value of `.ToString()` won't be accessible anymore, right?

Edit: in other words, something like

```
var crypto = new Rfc...(secureString.ToString());
```

Comment: For one, that wouldn't solve his problem, as the `string` instance still may not be GC'd for an undefined amount of time. For two, no doubt he does not want to use `System.Security.SecureString` as the password every time (since `SecureString` does not provide an overload of `ToString`).

Comment: The System.Security.SecureString.ToString method simply returns "System.Security.SecureString" no matter which string is actually stored in it. So the ToString method **cannot** be used to get the actual value of the SecureString instance.
The System.Security.SecureString class does not override the Object.ToString method, so when you call ToString on a System.Security.SecureString object you are actually calling Object.ToString which simply returns the name of the Type on which it was called ("return this.GetType().ToString();").