# How to remove exposed secure string from memory

Tags: c#, security, memory

currently I have issue on project where secure string is exposed like this:

```
IntPtr unmanagedString = IntPtr.Zero;
try
{
        unmanagedString = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(secureString);
        string str = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(unmanagedString);
        ...
        ...
}
finally
{
        Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(ptr);
}
```

After `Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(secureString)` call, copy of secure string content is saved in unmanaged memory. Even after `Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(ptr)` is called string can be easily found with memory tools, by simply searching for all strings.

Is there a way to completely remove it or at least go around it in some way, like overwrite it?

Comment: You may be *zeroing the memory*, but what about the other memory you allocated with with `string str = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(unmanagedString);` in fact every time you modify the string its going to create more copies. The rule of thumb is *"if you want to keep things secure, don't put them in apps that people can rummage through"*

Comment: (disclaimer: I never worked with `SecureString`; or pointers in C# for that matter) - does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3567531/1336590 -- as far as I understood, `SecureString` saves you from stupid mistakes (dump to logfile or something similar). But as soon as a `string` instance is created, that's it. Now it's in memory for "everyone" to read.

Comment: As I have tested, ```string str``` gets garbage collated later on. However  ```unmanagedString = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(secureString);``` creates instance in unmanaged memory, where garbage do not work. While clearing this manually do not seem to take any effect.

Comment: Also I will test this class out, maybe it will help.

Comment: `ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode` will call `ZeroMemory` and it will clear the memory allocated by `SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode`. there are other reasons why managed memory will hang around after the GC

Comment: @Corak Thanks, this seems to work! [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3567531/1336590)